# How many dragon parts do I need for a complete BoTW play-through?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

How many dragon parts do I need for all the shrines and armour upgrades in a  complete Breath of the Wild play-through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In total, you'll need these parts from *each* of the 3 dragons:

- 4 horn shards
- 4 scales
- 3 fang shards
- 3 claws
- 1 of any piece (for the associated Spring)

Here's a list for each dragon:

## Dinraal

(the red fire dragon)

- 1 of any for the Spring of Wisdom
- 2 horn shards for Champion's Tunic ★★★★
- 1 scale for Fierce Deity Mask ★
- 1 claw for Fierce Deity Mask ★★
- 1 fang shard for Fierce Deity Mask ★★★
- 2 scales for Trousers of the Wild ★
- 2 claws for Cap of the Wild ★★
- 2 fang shards for Trousers of the Wild ★★★
- 2 horn shards for Trousers of the Wild ★★★★

## Farosh

(the green electric dragon)

- 1 scale for Fierce Deity Mask ★
- 2 horn shards for Champion's Tunic ★★
- 1 claw for Fierce Deity Mask ★★
- 1 fang shard for Fierce Deity Mask ★★★
- 2 scales for Trousers of the Wild ★
- 2 claws for Trousers of the Wild ★★
- 2 fang shards for Trousers of the Wild ★★★
- 2 horn shards for Trousers of the Wild ★★★★

## Naydra

(the blue ice dragon)

- 1 of any for the Spring of Courage
- 2 horn shards for Champion's Tunic ★★★
- 1 scale for Fierce Deity Boots ★
- 1 claw for Fierce Deity Boots ★★
- 1 fang shard for Fierce Deity Boots ★★★
- 2 scales for Trousers of the Wild ★
- 2 claws for Tunic of the Wild ★★
- 2 fang shards for Trousers of the Wild ★★★
- 2 horn shards for Trousers of the Wild ★★★★